# Unable to delete records from SQL Server tables using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm developing a desktop application for inventory management.

I have 3 tables in SQL Server:

1. TRANSACTIONS
2. MATERIAL_TRANSACTION
3. TRANSACTION_DETAILS

I've created a stored procedure to insert as well as update all the above mentioned tables.

`TRANSACTIONS` is my master table. So, I use update query to update its columns.
But records of the other two tables, which are the detail tables, need to be deleted before inserting new rows in the database.

I'm unable to delete the rows in this stored procedure. Please help!

I've used the following SQL Server stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SAVE_TRANSACTION] 
    @ID NVARCHAR(50),
    @REF_NO NVARCHAR(50),
    @VCH_DATE DATE,
    @VCH_TYPE INT,
    @CR_AC INT,
    @DR_AC INT,
    @DOCKET_NO NVARCHAR(50),
    @TRANSPORT NVARCHAR(50),
    @DELIVERY_NOTE NTEXT,
    @S_NAR NVARCHAR(100),
    @L_NAR NTEXT,
    @IS_REVERSE_CHARGE INT,
    @INVOICE_REF INT,
    @BUYER NVARCHAR(50),
    @BUYER_CONTACT NVARCHAR(50),
    @BUYER_ADDRESS NTEXT,
    @BUYER_GSTIN NVARCHAR(50),
    @BUYER_STATE NVARCHAR(50),
    @BUYER_REG_TYPE INT,
    @MATERIAL_TRANSACTION dbo.TVP_MATERIAL_TRANSACTION READONLY,
    @TRANSACTION_DETAILS dbo.TVP_TRANSACTION_DETAILS READONLY,
    @RETURN INT OUTPUT 
AS
    DECLARE @TRAN_ID INT
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    DELETE FROM MATERIAL_TRANSACTION 
    WHERE ID > 0 
      AND TRANSACTION_ID = @ID;

    DELETE FROM TRANSACTION_DETAILS 
    WHERE ID > 0 
      AND TRANSACTION_ID = @ID;

    IF (@ID = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.TRANSACTIONS(REF_NO, VCH_DATE, VCH_TYPE, CR_AC, DR_AC,
                                     DOCKET_NO, TRANSPORT, DELIVERY_NOTE,
                                     S_NAR, L_NAR, IS_REVERSE_CHARGE,
                                     INVOICE_REF, BUYER, BUYER_CONTACT, BUYER_ADDRESS,
                                     BUYER_GSTIN, BUYER_STATE, BUYER_REG_TYPE)
        VALUES (@REF_NO, @VCH_DATE, @VCH_TYPE, @CR_AC, @DR_AC,
                @DOCKET_NO, @TRANSPORT, @DELIVERY_NOTE,
                @S_NAR, @L_NAR, @IS_REVERSE_CHARGE,
                @INVOICE_REF, @BUYER, @BUYER_CONTACT, @BUYER_ADDRESS,
                @BUYER_GSTIN, @BUYER_STATE, @BUYER_REG_TYPE);

        SET @TRAN_ID = @@IDENTITY
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.TRANSACTIONS
        SET REF_NO = @REF_NO,
            VCH_DATE = @VCH_DATE, VCH_TYPE = @VCH_TYPE,
            CR_AC = @CR_AC, DR_AC = @DR_AC,
            DOCKET_NO = @DOCKET_NO,
            TRANSPORT = @TRANSPORT, DELIVERY_NOTE = @DELIVERY_NOTE,
            S_NAR = @S_NAR, L_NAR = @L_NAR,
            IS_REVERSE_CHARGE = @IS_REVERSE_CHARGE,
            INVOICE_REF = @INVOICE_REF,
            BUYER = @BUYER, BUYER_CONTACT = @BUYER_CONTACT,
            BUYER_ADDRESS = @BUYER_ADDRESS,
            BUYER_GSTIN = @BUYER_GSTIN, BUYER_STATE = @BUYER_GSTIN,
            BUYER_REG_TYPE = @BUYER_REG_TYPE
        WHERE 
            ID = @ID;

        SET @TRAN_ID = @ID;
    END

    --UPDATE MATERIAL_TRANSACTION SET IS_DELETED=1 WHERE TRANSACTION_ID=@ID;
    --  UPDATE TRANSACTION_DETAILS SET IS_DELETED=1 WHERE TRANSACTION_ID=@ID;
    INSERT INTO TRANSACTION_DETAILS (TRANSACTION_ID, AC_ID, TRAN_TYPE,
                                     CR_AMT, DR_AMT, AMT_PERCENT, IS_PARENT)
        SELECT 
            @TRAN_ID, [AC_ID], [TRAN_TYPE], 
            [CR_AMT], [DR_AMT], [AMT_PERCENT], [IS_PARENT] 
        FROM 
            @TRANSACTION_DETAILS TVP

    INSERT INTO MATERIAL_TRANSACTION (TRANSACTION_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QTY,
                                      UNIT_ID, DESCRIPTION, HSN_CODE,
                                      PRICE, DISCOUNT_AMT, DISCOUNT_PERCENT,
                                      CGST_PERCENT, SGST_PERCENT, IGST_PERCENT,
                                      CGST_AMT, SGST_AMT, IGST_AMT)
        SELECT 
            @TRAN_ID, [PRODUCT_ID], [QTY],
            [UNIT_ID], [DESCRIPTION], [HSN_CODE],
            [PRICE], [DISCOUNT_AMT], [DISCOUNT_PERCENT],
            [CGST_PERCENT], [SGST_PERCENT], [IGST_PERCENT],
            [CGST_AMT], [SGST_AMT], [IGST_AMT] 
        FROM 
            @MATERIAL_TRANSACTION TVP

    SELECT @RETURN = @TRAN_ID
END
```

Comment: The @ID parameter is declared as nvarchar(50) yet the literals in the code are integers. The parameter should match the data type of `TRANSACTION_ID` in the underlying tables.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)